# SQL, how to extract maximum occurrence of an entry

Tags: sql

```
SELECT a.name,a.birth_year,COUNT(a.name)
FROM HUMAN a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT b.citizenship
                    FROM  NATIONALITY b
                    WHERE b.citizenship='Indian')
GROUP BY a.name,a.birth_year;
```

I want to extract the name which has the maximum number of occurrences in the HUMAN table and the citizenship of that person is Indian. I tried doing MAX(COUNT(a.name)) but it doesn't work. Any idea's how to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server, oracle, mysql...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
select h.name
from human h join
     citizenship c
     on h.name = b.name
where c.citizenship = 'Indian'
group by h.name
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

The `fetch first 1 rows only` is ANSI standard, but not all databases support it.  Your database might use `limit`, `top` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name,a.birth_year,COUNT(a.name) as c
FROM HUMAN a
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT b.citizenship
                FROM  NATIONALITY b
                WHERE b.citizenship='Indian')
GROUP BY a.name,a.birth_year
ORDER by c DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be easy with a nested select query.

```
Select max(count1),name1 from (
SELECT a.name name1,COUNT(a.name)     count1 FROM HUMAN a WHERE EXISTS(SELECT  b.citizenship FROM NATIONALITY b WHERE b.citizenship='Indian') GROUP BY a.name)
```